# how to add an object to array immediately after set to empty "[ ]" Vue

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js, conditional-statements, push

I need after call a function, set to empty an array and immediately add a new one to there. 
This is becouse when an @click event is called i need to call a dialog and populate the content of this with a dynamic component (called them with a slug propertie), so the array should be change accordily to pass the slug propertie to the component.
My code is:

```
slugs: []

slugConversacion(slug) {
    if (this.slugs > 0) {
        this.slugs = []

    // this.slugs.splice(this.slugs.indexOf(slug), 0);
    // this.$delete(this.slugs, this.slugs.indexOf(slug))

    } 
    else {
        this.slugs.push(slug); 
    }
  }

<Conversacion
   v-for="slug in slugs"
   :key="slug.id"
   :slug="slug.slug"
></Conversacion>
```

This not work because when i click the event slugConversacion() set and empty array and only when clicked again, populate. I think that is for the if/else conditional.

What would be the right approach ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
if (this.slugs.length > 0) {
    this.slugs = [];
}

this.slugs.push(slug);
```

If you have trouble with setting array to empty with assigning [] to array and loosing reactivity, then you can try next thing.

This works for me as the last resort:

```
var i = slugs.length;

while(i --){
    slugs.splice(i, 1);
}
```

You should do splice in revers mode because of index confusion: every time will be remained array element with index 1 if you will go throw the loop via

```
slugs.forEach((item, index) => {
    slugs.splice(index, 1);
});
```

And after that you can do:

```
this.slugs.push(slug);
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer i figgerout that I forgot to add .length in my code. Now works correctly with the first approach. Many thanks for the help!